# Detect when to use a vs an

Tags: ios, localization

I have a service that allows user's (admins) to change the terminology the site uses. My designer wants me to use the format "A  Group". The problem is, for some terminology, it should be "An" not "A".

Is there any way to reliably detect which to use? What about localization?

I can brute force it and get 90% of the way by checking the first letter for consonant vs vowel. That won't work for all words though. And that doesn't cover any language except English.

Comment: The rules are pretty complicated.  I recommend this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/152/10411

Comment: I'm not sure that English.SE is a great place to ask questions on localization (particularly given he's concerned about using a method that will only cover English), @Dave.

Comment: @Shog9 the pointer to Eng.SE is to grok the rules behind when you'd use "a" vs "an" (but you're right, it wouldn't help w/ localization). Once you get the rules, writing the code to follow them becomes much simpler. But asking on SO about rules of grammar seems off-topic to me.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you've got only 2 ways:

1- You need to check the first letter and process all the sentence by checking its letters to see if there is any non-English letters.

2- Provide a dictionary of English nouns then you can easily check your word to find if it needs an "a" or "an".

Answer (score 0):

Although the "*a* versus *an*" issue is very specific, what you're describing here is a natural language processing issue.  Essentially you are being asked to write code that generates a grammatically correct piece of text.

I think you should try to to explain the implications to the designer, especially if you end up localizing in other languages. Your time is probably better spent working on your app's business logic than on language processing.